# Strange python error when up loading a file into a dictionary

Tags: python, error-handling

Im not sure what is going wrong with my user_dictionary. I created the get method ot check and make sure it was uploading correctly. The keys are set as the user name, and i want each key to be equal to a list of rating values. The keys seem to load fine as you can see in the terminal, but when i call to see a specific keys value i get this error ([] anyone know what this means? Also i added the file that i am loading into user_dictionary so you could see the layout.

1 Line of the file im uploading 
ben,5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -3 5 0 0 0 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 3 0 1 0
and so on with different names as first word

```
def read_users(user_file_name):
    returnDict={}
    try:
        f = open(user_file_name,"r")

        for line in f:
            temp=line.split(',')
            a=temp[0]
            #returnDict[a]=[]
            temp.pop(0)

            value= map(int, temp)
            returnDict[a]=[value]

        return returnDict;
    except:
        return;
```

class Library:

```
def __init__(self,books_filename,ratings_filename):
    self.book_list = read_books(books_filename)
    self.user_dictionary = read_users(ratings_filename)
def getUser_Dictionary(self):
    #print(self.user_dictionary.keys())
    print(self.user_dictionary['nathan'])
```

Comment: [] isn't an error. It's an empty list

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an error, but an empty list for your values. This is because you are setting the value to a map object and not to the value you want.

Replace these lines:

```
value= map(int, temp)
returnDict[a]=[value]
```

with:

```
value = list(map(int, temp))
returnDict[a] = value
```

also returnDict is a very confusing variable name that I would avoid.